# Search() StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I was asked in a problem to make a static ***recursive*** method called search that searches for a character in a string and if it finds it prints it's location, if it doesn't, it returns -1

this is my code

```
public static int search(String s , char c)
{
    boolean flag = true;
    if (flag == false && s.length() == 0)
        return -(s.length() + 1);
    else
        if (s.charAt(0) == c)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = false;
            return 1 + search(s.substring(1) , c);
        }
```

I'm using a flag to see if it doesn't find it after coursing through all the string, it'll preform all of the string's length minus the string's length - 1,
But I always end up with a "**StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**" error. Where is that error located exactly? Thanks in advance! :D

edit: it works if i input a character that exists in the string like **n** in **animal**, but if i enter **o** and the string be **animal** , it'll give me the error.

**edit 2: I got it to work by removing the flag and traversing the string from the last character, thanks everyone! :D**

Comment: your if statment always is false and else work

Comment: this condition `boolean flag = true;  if (flag == false && s.length() == 0)` doesn't really work. `flag` is always true.

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc I don't understand how, i tried tracing it, if i enter for example sorata and z, it should turn false from the beginning right, I tried to trace it and that was what I got, can u explain more please?

Comment: I'll bet you think the variable flag is somehow passing information back up the recursive call stack about when to stop doing recursion.  It's not.

Comment: @KevinAnderson ah i forgot about that completely and got loops mixed up with recursion, thanks i'll work on it :D

Comment: why don't you use a predefined function ?

Comment: return s.indexOf(c);
it will return the index of the character if the character is exist otherwise it will return -1

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first index out of bounds will happen at else block s.substring(1)...

ex: `s="a", c="b"`

> 1. `flag=true`
> 2. if `(flag == false && s.length() == 0)` this will fail and go to else block
> 3. in else block,  `if (s.charAt(0) == c)` , here "a"=="c" fails go to else block
> 4. in the inner else block, you have  `return 1 + search(s.substring(1) , c);` this line will look for the String index
>      position 1, which is not available and throws
>      stringindexoutofboundsexception

Comment: i'll try removing the flag completely and work on the string by reverse to avoid the stringindexoutofboundsexception

Answer (score 0):

Because of your recursion `flag` is always `true` so your first `if` will never be `true`.

It would help if `flag` would be a class member. In that case you need to reset the `flag` before each search.

But it would also leads to an exception if you invoke your search with an empty string. So I think you do not need the `flag`.

Comment: yea, I got iterations mixed up and thought it would carry the false value after each recursion, I removed the flag completely and will try another approach without it

Answer (score 0):

There are few small issues with your code. 
`flag` is always true, so if conditions is always false:

```
boolean flag = true;
    if (flag == false && s.length() == 0) // always false, even if 
// s.length() is 0
```

Why do you need this `flag` variable? This assignment `flag = false;`  has no effect by the way. You either need to change signature of your search method `search(String s , char c, boolean flag)`  and pass it as 3rd param, or probably remove `flag` completely. 
Second thing is that your function will return positive result for all strings will lengths more than 2 characters. 
`return 1 + search(s.substring(1) , c);`  and `return -(s.length() + 1);`. The last condition will be executed only if there are no more characters in the string (let's say we are not using `flag` variable).

```
if (s.length() == 0) // there are no more characters in the str
     return -(s.length() + 1); // we return -1
```

But in this case we already have `return 1 + search(s.substring(1) , c);` which will lead to `1 + -(0+1)`. for  `search("a",'d')`, 
`1 + 1 -(0+1)` for `search("ab",'d')` and so on.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yea i got iterations and recursion mixed up, I'll remove flag and try to work on it again, Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you dint mind searching from the end of the string you can do this:

```
public static int search(String s , char c) {      
if (s==null || s.length() == 0)
return -1;
else if (s.charAt(s.length()-1) == c)
{
return s.length();
} else {
int pos=search(s.substring(0,s.length()-1) , c);
return pos;
}
}
```

Comment: I was about to search the string by reverse to avoid the stringindexoutofboundsexception, I'll work on it

Answer (score 0):

Error comes from `return 1 + search(s.substring(1) , c);` this line.

if you are searching for **'o'**, in the last iteration **s=l** and **s.substring(1)** doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You have to move out the `flag` variable outside the method, as on every recursive call it is being set to true and hence the first `if` block will never get executed. loopCount will meet your purpose, you don't need to use flag variable.

```
    static int loopCount =0;
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println(search("animal", 'o'));
    }

    public static int search(String s , char c)
    {
        loopCount++;
        if (s.length() == 0){
            return -loopCount;
        }
        else if (s.charAt(0) == c)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1 + search(s.substring(1) , c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: U mean make it an instance variable? and what is loopCount exactly?, Sorry I'm a student so i'm fairly new

Comment: loopcount will be used to subtract the values("1") you have added while calling the search method recursively. For ex. if you want to search 'o' in "animal" string. the search method will be called 5 times recursively and every time 1 is being added in return value. So total return value will be 5 on last call. So you have to subtract the loop count=6 from 5 to get the desired output "-1".

Comment: although flag variable is not needed but still you want to use it, you can make it instance not local to method.